# Как редактировать строчку в DataGrd в новом окне WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть такой *DataGrid* на *MainWndow*

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG_TALON"  VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding IMA}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Фамилия" Binding="{Binding FAM}" Width="*"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Который получает таблицу из базы данных

```
DG_TALON.ItemsSource = ASUMEntities.GetContext().KARD.ToList();
```

В другом окне, *Window1*, имеются *TextBox`ы* в которые надо вывести для редактирования строчку из *DG_TALON* и потом сохранить это в Базе Данных  
Помогите, пожалуйста, ломаю голову уже неделю.

Comment: Где ваши попытки? Вот "неделю ломаете голову", не уж то нету кривого прототипа, хотяб наброска того, как это реализовать? В чем конкретно у вас трудности?

Comment: Кривой прототип через связь многие ко многим, но тогда в БД не сохраняются изменения. Нашел старый репозиторий но не хватает опыта в нём разобраться

Comment: Попробуйте начать писать код, а потом если не получится, выкладывайте его в вопрос, посмотрим, как починить.